# How to convert this MYSQL SQL to HIVE SQL？

Tags: sql, sql-server, hive, hiveql

The table ProductOrder columns include:

```
id   shopid starttime endtime 
1    123    2018-04-27  2018-04-28
2    234    2018-04-23  2018-04-30
3    189    2018-05-01  2018-05-30
4    321    2018-05-01  2018-05-29
```

I wan't to query for valid shop counts between two days and count by each day of latest month,the valid shop counts means the starttime<= $curDate <= endtime,and curDate is a variable of the each day of the leatest month.

Today is 2018-04-27，so the query result should be:

```
day          count
2018-04-27    2
2018-04-26    1
2018-04-25    1
2018-04-24    1
2018-04-23    1
2018-04-22    0
2018-04-21    0
……………………………………
2018-03-26    0
```

I achieve this requirement in MYSQL.This SQL can work well in MYSQL.How can I convert to Hive Sql？

```
SELECT
    DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL days_ago.days DAY) day,
    COUNT(distinct(shopID)) count
FROM
(SELECT 0 days UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
 SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION
 SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 14 UNION
 SELECT 15 UNION SELECT 16 UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 18 UNION SELECT 19 UNION
 SELECT 20 UNION SELECT 21 UNION SELECT 22 UNION SELECT 23 UNION SELECT 24 UNION
 SELECT 25 UNION SELECT 26 UNION SELECT 27 UNION SELECT 28 UNION SELECT 29)
    AS days_ago
LEFT JOIN ProductOrder
    ON DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL days_ago.days DAY) <= ProductOrder.endtime
    AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL days_ago.days DAY) >= ProductOrder.starttime
    AND status = 2
GROUP BY days_ago.days;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Hive` does not support Non equi join conditions, they can be placed to the WHERE clause instead. Use `STACK` instead of many UNION subqueries.

```
select DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, days_ago.days) day, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT(shopID)) count 
from
(
select stack(30, --the number of elements
           0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
          10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
          20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29) as (days) 
 ) days_ago
LEFT JOIN ProductOrder po ON status = 2
WHERE (DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, days_ago.days) <= po.endtime  
  AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, days_ago.days) >= po.starttime)
   OR po.shopID is NULL --allow nulls  
GROUP BY DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, days_ago.days);
```

Comment: Complex expressions in ON clause are supported, starting with Hive 2.2.0 (see [Hive wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins#LanguageManualJoins-JoinSyntax)).

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander Thanks, this is useful information. Unfortunately I have Hive 1.2.0 and cannot check how  it works

Comment: You're welcome! Script executed successfully with Hive 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, days_ago.days), 
       COUNT(DISTINCT(shopID)) count 
FROM
(
    SELECT explode(array(
           0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
          10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
          20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29)) as days
) days_ago 
LEFT JOIN ProductOrder po ON 
(
    DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, days_ago.days) <= po.endtime  
    AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, days_ago.days) >= po.starttime 
    AND status = 2
) 
GROUP BY days_ago.days;
```